# Simple Ciphers to Create Secure Passwords

Tags: passwords

A shift cipher shifts every letter of a word by "n" amount and creates new word. The number of possible keys in the shift cipher is equal the size of the alphabet set from which the word is derived. For example if the words are derived from the lowercase letters there are 26 different keys.

The word "withcurious" with the shift-amount or key "1" gets transformed to "xjuidvsjpvt". Can such schemes be used by user to set passwords. One might argue that, in the case of shift cipher the number of keys are less. Therefore if the attacker learns this trick, he has to build only 26 dictionaries one with every shift amount. 0...25

But if one uses monoalphabetic or polyalphabetic substitution ciphers, in which every alphabet in a word is basically shifted by different amount, can it be used to create secure passwords, considering that a random key is assigned to every user. With the alphabet set of size 94 that include lowercase, uppercase, digit and symbols there are 94! different keys in case of monoalphabetic substitution ciphers and power(94;94) in case of polyalphabetic substitution ciphers. User can store the key (alphabetic mapping) securely, and may be use the name of the site and encrypt it with his secret key. The resulting ciphertext appears random and is set as password.

Can the passwords constructed under such scheme be considered as secure if it satisfies the minimum length requirement( > 12)? Is it feasible to implement such scheme?

Comment: Can one? probably - most passwords also require complexity, and it is unlikely that a shift cipher will generate the resulting complexity.  Most users are also going to find that the resulting cipher is too complex.  Also most simple ciphers (that can be done unaided by a human) are NOT resilient against cryptanalysis.   Ultimately the question rests on how you measure security and what your threat profile looks like.

Comment: Mapping can be stored securely in the form of a table, every symbol is mapped to different symbol in case of monoalphabetic cipher. This mapping is essentially the key. The number of such mappings are enormous 94! (94 factorial). One such mapping is assigned for every user. Cryptanalysis is possible on long ciphertexts but in our case the ciphertext is password itself and is secret.

Comment: I think you're falling into the [XY trap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the problem you need to solve?

Comment: Creating difficult to guess but easy to remember passwords using Classical Ciphers which has large key space.

Comment: Instead of creating random passwords for every site, user can use the secret mapping of symbols to create secure passwords. For e.g. the user can simply encrypt the website name or any other string using the stored mapping and use the resulting ciphertext as his password for that site. Can we use such schemes to create difficult to guess passwords?

Comment: The user cannot remember such mapping, but he can store it securely. I am basically talking about creating passwords using the substitution Cipher. The resulting passwords will be hard to guess.

Comment: This is doubly ridiculous. First you really make it hard for users to remember and type passwords. If you used your scheme to login to 10 systems per day, how much time would it take you compared to vanilla passwords, even with whatever aids you want? And then, why on earth does everyone want to create "memorable and secure passwords" when they can't even guarantee said graalwords won't be stolen in the first place.

Comment: @Steve, User do not have to remember the ciphertext as the password. May be a cipher keyboard can be provided, so that when user types in alphabet it gets mapped to different alphabet according to the key underneath. One such keyboard is provided to every user and he stores them securely. He can use any simple text as his "plaintext" and use the "mapping (key)" to create the "ciphertext". This resulting ciphertext will be his password. I don't see any problem in making it hard for users to remember, as I already said, the key or the mapping can be stored by the user.

Comment: @Steve, even if the password is stolen, cryptanalaysis on smaller ciphertexts will not be effective, the attack will need longer ciphertexts to perform frequency analysis. The user can still reset his password using the same key. I again want emphasize that user do not have to remember the "key", but stores them or take a print of it. He just remember his "secret plaintext" which when combined with "secret key" gives "secret password".

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm abroad with 5% battery on my phone and I *really* need to transfer some money from my banking app because I forgot to pay the hotel at which I'm staying tonight, I'm currently at the bus stop on the way there and it's 10PM. Let me open my luggage to find the keyboard. ;)

Comment: Not to mention changes of hardware, using multiple devices and having to (securely!) carry around that cypher-keyboard, using someone else's machine... If you can't use an auth credential in 95-100% of the cases when you need to do so, that credential just sucks. No matter how good it looks on paper or in the lab.

Comment: Now, to be more constructive: I recommend you explain what precise security/usability issue(s) you are trying to solve, for which user population, under which threat model and with which budget for every possibly involved stakeholder. Really, that is needed. **What has made current solutions fail to answer the problem?** Then, take some time to enumerate and justify the properties of your solution within that scope. Then we can point out issues and make suggestions in a constructive and helpful way.

Comment: @Steve the cipher keyboard don't have to be implemented as hardware, it can be a virtual cipher keyboard for creating passwords.

Comment: @Steve the details of the cipher are hidden in the cipher keyboard, you can set any sufficient long string as password using the cipher keyboard. Typing it will result in ciphertext, which is your actual password. The cipher key board corresponds to one key derived from enormous key space. The key and therefore the cipher keyboard should remain secret and allocated to every user. I am trying to create secure passwords, without affecting the usability(memory of the user).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17254/discussion-between-curious-and-steve-dl).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you are proposing is an algorithm with a seed value.  This seed value is the users plaintext password.  This is essentially no different from using a good [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) (like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)) on a master password to then create derived passwords.

That said, the common and most sensible advice is **don't roll your own**.  If it's a KDF you are after, then use a known good algorithm.  If it's simply secure passwords that you are after, a much simpler (and more secure) alternative is to use a password manager like Keepass.

Answer (score 0):

Such a scheme provides no benefit over purely random passwords. They're still difficult to remember, but easier for a computer to guess than pure random strings.

Instead, you should use passphrases. Length trumps complexity when it comes to entropy, and words are easier to remember than random characters.

Obligatory XKCD: 
http://xkcd.com/936/

You might think taking advice from a comic isn't the best idea, but try it for yourself:
https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm

You can plainly see here that a passphrase comprised of several common words is stronger than 8-12 random characters.

Tr0ub4dor&3 - 5.75 x 10^21

correct horse battery staple - 3.90 x 10^49

xjuidvsjpvt - 3.82 x 10^15

If these passwords have to be generated for the user, have your script pick four or five random dictionary words of at least 5 characters in length. No algorithms, super easy to remember.

Comment: xjuidvsjpvt  is just one example, using large alphabet set of size 94 will give different password. Moreover the strength measured by grc site is not correct. Longer doesn't imply security. The correct to measure the strength is how randomly those words are drawn to create the passphrase. If only 1000 words are used then the strength of the passphrase consisting of 4 words will be just 40 bits which is 10^12 and not 10^49 as claimed by grc

Comment: -1 for pointing to a snake oil website with a badly broken "entropy estimator".

Answer (score 0):

What about Playfair cipher? There's an online [tool](https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/playfair-cipher) to encode/decode a message, but you could also do it yourself on a piece of paper. It requires a keyword which you use to create a grid of letters, then you combine that with a word or phrase that you encode using the grid you created using the keyword. You would have to know the keyword to decode the string. It doesn't support numbers but you could add them afterwards. 'this is a secret' would be 'VFLQLQCPODDKZRECOU', but you would have to have the keyword to figure that out. You could do things manually like alternating lowercase & uppercase or adding numbers randomly too.

Comment: You also must omit one or more letters so it's an even 5x5 grid of 25 letters. Generally 'j' is omitted, but you can choose a different letter. That makes it very difficult for anybody (including a computer) to figure it out without the keyword.